# how do my position my ::after content to always be at the inside end of the <a>?

Tags: html, css

i have the following

**HTML:**

```html
<div id='button'>
    <a href=''>My Link</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#button a {
    display: block;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width:250px;
    text-align:center;
}

#button a::after {
    content: " \25b6";
    color:#000000;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/)

Now as you can see from the jsfiddle link i have a black triangle at the end of the text of my `<a>` but what i want is for it to be at the end of the inside of the `<a>` (within the red) so that should the box re-size the triangle will move along with the end and ideally for it to be vertically aligned to the middle for [multiple lines](http://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/3/)

I have tried applying [an `::after` to the div](https://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/1/) and applying the styles [to the `<div>` instead of the `<a>`](https://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/2/) to no avail so i am wondering what i am missing here.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/5/

Comment: @Sampson yes, thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to position the arrow to the right, you'll need to do something along these lines:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.container::after {
    content: "\25B6";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This locks the element to the right (`right:0`) of the container, and positions it half-way down from the top of the container (`top:50%`). We then move the element back up vertically, a distance equal to half of its own height (`transform:translateY(-50%)`).

The end-result can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdn7byfc/5/